# Positioning and Resizing handles similar to Apple Pages

Tags: ios, swift

In Apple's Pages app it allows you to add an image or text box or shape layer to the page then resize it by tapping on it and the handles appear. A similar thing also happens in the Pixelmator app and a few others. Is this something made by Apple that I can use in my app or would I have to build it in myself?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no system support for resize handles and you will need to build it yourself. That's what I've done when I needed them. I added views on top of the thing that I wanted to resize, with pan gesture recognizers attached.

I have an app called [**CIFilterTest on Github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/CIFilterTest/blob/master/how_cifiltertest_works.md) (written in Objective-C, unfortunately) that uses resize handles to let the user move around points and rects when they are needed for the various Core Image filters. Even though it's written in Objective-C it should give you the idea.

Note that most Core Image filters run VERY slowly on the simulator, making the app seem extremely laggy. That's an artifact of running Core Image filters on the simulator. It runs much faster on an actual iOS device.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help. I will take a look at you're project.